# Is there an event for customer account registration in Magento?

Tags: php, events, magento, observer-pattern

I would like to be able to run some functionality with a `module` that I am building whenever a `customer registers` an account, but I can't seem to find any `event` that is fired upon a `new customer registration`.

Does anybody know of an `event` that is dispatched for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that there isn't an event for that.

Comment: Turns out that you can hook into a specific event, see my new post for details.

Comment: @Prattski: +1. Thank you for actually answering the question, and *not* polluting this question with an alternative solution that isn't modular (like all these controller observers).

Answer (score 45):

Whenever I'm looking for an event, I'll temporarily edit the `Mage.php` file to output all the events for a particular request.

```
File: app/Mage.php
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Mage::log('Event: ' . $name); //not using Mage::log, as 
    //file_put_contents('/tmp/test.log','Dispatching '. $name. "\n",FILE_APPEND); //poor man's log
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    #$result = self::registry('events')->dispatch($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

and then perform whatever action it is I'm trying to hook into.  Magento events are logically named, so scanning/sorting through the resulting logs usually reveals what I'm after.

Comment: Definitely helpful, no doubt.  However, I would still like an answer to my question, so I will not consider this an answer.

Comment: Thanks Alan.  I said it was helpful, but ultimately you didn't actually answer the question.  It's you asking me what color of Green to use, and I tell you to use Sherman Williams glossy.  It's helpful, but not an actual answer to the question.

Comment: It is if you have the Sherman Williams glossy sitting right next to you

Comment: Also, I feel this answer is above and beyond. It not only answers your question but helps you to not have to ever ask a similar one again. "Give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach him to fish, feed him forever"

Comment: Haha, brilliant I think Alan has spoken on multiple levels (as he always does). If you need an answer whether something happens why not just log the very core of magento to see what happens. This also answered an additional question for me. Side note Commercebug poops gold pay Alan - Cheers

Comment: I had the same question as the OP. Sifting through everything below is the actual answer which is the event customer_register_success. Since Alan's answer has the most votes I thought putting it in the comments might save some work for anyone else that comes upon this question. +1 for Alan's answer and +1 for Paul Grigoruta below.

Comment: It appeared to me that it doesn't output **all** events - for example placing order fires up event called `sales_quote_save_after` but I can't see anything like that in my system.log

Comment: Good tip, but this is not an answer, as for me @ahe_borriglione have proper solution as it works for me.

Comment: @AlanStorm ok, I will do the job. THANK YOU, mr. Storm :) This helped a lot

Comment: This is probably the single most useful answer I've read on SO in the last month. You rock, @AlanStorm

Comment: -1, this did't show all the events in my 1.9.2.2 version. Actually this helped: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92169/how-to-get-magento-1-9-ces-events-list-and-which-event-is-called-when?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Sunry Did you uncomment the file_put_contents line above?  If the above didn't log events for you then you're working with a system that's been significantly modified from a stock Magento instance.

Comment: @AlanStorm Yes, I uncomment the file_put_contents line. The output like: `Dispatching resource_get_tablename
Dispatching resource_get_tablename
Dispatching resource_get_tablename
Dispatching resource_get_tablename
Dispatching resource_get_tablename
Dispatching core_collection_abstract_load_before
Dispatching core_collection_abstract_load_after
Dispatching core_collection_abstract_load_before
Dispatching core_collection_abstract_load_after
Dispatching core_collection_abstract_load_before
Dispatching core_collection_abstract_load_after
Dispatching always`

Comment: @Sunry Right -- when that happens you're seeing all the events that fire *for that HTTP request*.  Perform the action you want, sort out the duplicates, and you can always find the event you're looking for (if it actually fires)

Comment: @AlanStorm Just didn't get the event I wanted,so I downvote your answer. But it's still a good hint. Now I can't cancel the downvote unless you edit your answer.

Answer (score 19):

customer_register_success is what you are looking for:

```
<config>
  <frontend>
    <events>
      <customer_register_success>
        <observers>
          <your_module>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>your_module/observer</class>
            <method>yourMethod</method>
          </your_module>
        </observers>
      </customer_register_success>
    </events>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: AFAIK, this event only works if account is created via url: customer/account/create

Comment: @MagePsycho is absolutely right, this event won't fire when a user registers from checkout. Be aware!

Answer (score 16):

I discovered how to achieve this today. It involves using one of the generic controller events.  This node in the `config.xml` will hook into the right event:

```
<events>
 ....
  <controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createPost>
    <observers>
     <your_module_here>...etc
```

The `controller_action_postdispatch_REQUESTPATH` event is thrown for every controller that extends `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` (which is basically all of them) which makes it very easy to target. Ditto for `controller_action_predispatch_REQUESTPATH`.

Comment: It failed for me with the camelCase "createPost", but when changed to `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createpost` this worked swell. Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely helpful. Just a quick question. Observer gets called after the execution of action or before it??thanks

Comment: @SAM - "postDispatch" means after the Action has completed.  "preDispatch" is before.  You can choose to bind your Observer to either Event.

Comment: @jonathan, this is really a great help. Many Thanks.

Comment: this does not trigger when registering in checkout process

Comment: For posterity: This is a very bad solution because it doesn't trigger upon *any* new customer registration.  It will trigger only if a customer registers through *that* specific URL, which is not the only way for a customer to be registered in vanilla Magento, let alone with any number of modules installed.  Observing controller actions is *rarely* the right way to go.

Comment: For those who don't need a broader event, this might be the best solution if using Magento < 1.6, as it wasn't until 1.6 that the `customer_register_success` event was added to the account controller.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a bit surprised that none of the answers if solving the case completely.

Customer create can happen

1. by url customer/account/create
2. by register in checkout

I solved it by tracking two events:

*config.xml*

```
    <events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createpost>
            <observers>
                <myextensionkey_create_account>
                    <class>myextensionkey/observer</class>
                    <method>createAccount</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </myextensionkey_create_account>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createpost>
        <checkout_submit_all_after>
           <observers>
              <myextensionkey_checkout_create_account>
                    <class>myextensionkey/observer</class>
                    <method>createAccountCheckout</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
              </myextensionkey_checkout_create_account>
           </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
```

and in Observer.php

```
public function createAccount($observer) { ... } //Nothing special here

public function createAccountCheckout($observer) {
    if ($observer->getQuote()->getData('checkout_method') != Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_REGISTER) {
            return;
    }
```

Edit: I changed

```
<controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost>
```

into

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createpost>
```

because on predispatch the account is not created yet. There can be an error for example if the email already exists in the shop.

Comment: plus from me, as I'm wonder why this answer not checked as the right one.

Comment: where should Observer.php live?

Comment: @CollinAnderson

in: app/code/local_OR_community/YourPackageName/YourModuleName/Model/Observer.php

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a direct event for this, but you could use the **customer_save_commit_after** event. This event also guarantees you that the customer is save in the shop's database. The problem with this event is that is triggered twice. Bellow is an hack that allows you to use this event - the observer function is listed:

```
public function customer_save_commit_after($p_oObserver) {

    $l_oCustomer = $p_oObserver->getCustomer();

    if ($l_oCustomer->isObjectNew() && !$l_oCustomer->getMyCustomKeyForIsAlreadyProcessed()) {
        $l_oCustomer->setMyCustomKeyForIsAlreadyProcessed(true);
        // new customer
    }
    else {
        // existing customer
    }

    return false;

}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This is always returning `false` for me.

Answer (score 4):

You have to consider also when the user register on-the-fly on checkout: a Register on chekout. Thinking on this case, you can catch the "checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after" event with your own Observer class, and then this code...

```
if($observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod(true) == Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::CHECKOUT_METHOD_REGISTER){
    (...)
}
```

Anybody may say: *Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->getCheckoutMethod() is deprecated since 1.4!!*,but:

If we call the ortodox method Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->getCheckoutMethod(), waiting for something as "METHOD_REGISTER" this is executed:

```
if ($this->getCustomerSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            return self::METHOD_CUSTOMER;
        }
```

... "METHOD_CUSTOMER" is the name for a checkout with an already registrated user, not our case.... but yes!, because....

...the registration operation is perfomed before "checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after" event. Then we a have a METHOD_CUSTOMER now. Ups, something inconsistent?

Fortunatly, the Quote remains with the original value: CHECKOUT_METHOD_REGISTER

Any other idea for the registration on checkout?

Comment: This deprecated method is still available in 1.7.0.2.  I haven't checked any newer versions, so YMMV.

Comment: This deprecated method is still available in 1.9.2.3. I haven't checked any newer versions, so YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

You can try customer_save_after, the only thing that the registration sends this event twice

Comment: it seems that `customer_save_after` always gets called twice, whether its on registration or any other action.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are `customer_save_after` and `customer_save_before` (magento 1.5)

If you want to modify on-the-fly some data after form post, pick `customer_save_before`, change the data you want and that's all (the save action come after, so your change will be taken into account).

`$customer->save()` just doesn't work in `customer_save_after`. (fatal error) Use this observer to run a code after customer creation which are NOT related to customer data.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

customer_register_success

adminhtml_customer_save_after

these two are the default events when a customer is inserted into the database....
first event fires in frontend when a user registers and second event fires in the backend when a customer is created through admin panel...i hope you know how to register an observer for an event...hope this will help you...

Answer (score 2):

I was looking of the same thing. I believe the event is `customer_register_success`.

You can find a link for all events at:
http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/

Answer (score 2):

I found the event checkout_submit_all_after.

```
<checkout_submit_all_after>
   <observers>
      <my_example>
         <class>my_example/observer</class>
            <method>customerRegistered</method>                        
      </my_example>
   </observers>
</checkout_submit_all_after>
```

In my Observer.php I get the quote object that is passed in.

```
public function customerRegistered (Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    $checkout_method = $quote->getData();
    $checkout_method = $checkout_method['checkout_method'];                      

    if ($checkout_method == Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_REGISTER) {        
}
```

Do not use $quote->getCheckoutMethod() it gives you login_in instead. Not sure why. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hooking a checkout event seems a bad idea, if no further explanation is given why this would work.

Comment: Nice tip about $quote->getCheckoutMethod() it gives you login_in instead , +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that the `customer_login` and `customer_session_init` events are both thrown on account create.  You could register a listener for **either** and then check to see the **create date** on the account?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the customer_register_success event. It is triggered after the customer is succesfully created. Here is the link of event cheat sheets. Hope it also helps you.

```
http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/
```

Answer (score 0):

`customer_register_success` is the event dispatched after successful customer registration.
Here's from the code from `Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`::**454** in *magento 1.8*:

```
protected function _dispatchRegisterSuccess($customer)
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
        array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`customer_save_after` is the event which gets called after a new `customer registration`.

Read about all the `events` here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events

Comment: Not only will this event fire after registration, but whenever they or an admin makes any modifications to their account afterwards.

Answer (score -3):

event name：customer_registration_is_allowed

I'm not sure if this is you want,you can write a observer to test