# Accessing Magento Models from Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I'm not sure if this is possible, so if not, I welcome any alternative ways to accomplish this.  Basically, I want to set a Mage checkout session variable when the user selects a checkbox.  I currently have this *working* by redirecting to a controller that does the work and then redirecting back to checkout after the variable has been saved.  This takes a while and I feel like there should be a better way but I can't get it to work.

Here is the input checkbox declaration inside *methods.phtml*:

```
<input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="1" type="checkbox" name="payment[use_internal_credit]" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" class="checkbox" 
    onclick="checkout.update({'review': 1}); parent.location='<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getUseInternalCredit()): echo Mage::getUrl('customercredit/index/removeCreditUse/redirect/firecheckout'); else: echo Mage::getUrl('customercredit/index/updateCreditPost/redirect/firecheckout'); endif; ?>'" 
    <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getUseInternalCredit()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> />
```

This works but it's not very user friendly and takes a good 3-5 seconds to return back to the checkout page.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?  All I need to do is toggle the *useInternalCredit* session variable and then refresh the checkout review section.   The refresh is easy...it's accessing the Mage class on click that is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The system APIs are server-side, which means that client-side code cannot possibly reach them without any extra kind of request. This is a good thing, as otherwise any customer would be able to change thing arbitrarily at the model level.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way I'd do it, if it inspires you.

1. From the code you provide, it looks like the checkbox appears in the payment step. So I'd add the checkbox in the template file (`template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`).
2. make an observer to listen to `controller_action_postdispatch`. the method of this observer would check the full action name is 'checkout_onepage_savePaymentMethod'
3. in case of afirmative, it'd check if the post paremeter with key `payment[use_internal_credit]` (aka, the chekbox's name) is set and has value of 1 (the checkbox value, meaning the checkbox has been checked by the customer) and if so add whatever you want to in a session variable: `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setUniqueName($data['payment[use_internal_credit]']);` (`$data` being a reference to `$Controller->getRequest()->getPost();`)

You could probably make the observer listen to the event throwed specifically by the payment step, to find it, check out [Alan's Storm solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968294/is-there-an-event-for-customer-account-registration-in-magento/2968705#2968705), I just don't know which/if it is and I'm use to this one.

Let me know if it's not clear.