# Send admin email on registration success in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, registration

I'm trying to get [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11315398/653929) working to send on an email to admin upon successful registration. 'I think' i have it set up correctly ... but exactly notta is happening:

**config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <WACI_CustomerExt>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </WACI_CustomerExt>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <WACI_CustomerExt>
                <class>WACI_CustomerExt_Model</class>
            </WACI_CustomerExt>
        </models>
        <template>
            <email>
                <!-- regisration success -->
                <notify_new_customer module="WACI_CustomerExt">
                    <label>Admin notification on registration success</label>
                    <file>notify_new_customer.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </notify_new_customer>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <!-- regisration success -->
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                    <WACI_CustomerExt>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>waci_customerext/observer</class>
                        <method>customer_register_success</method>
                    </WACI_CustomerExt>
                </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**namespace/module/group/Observer.php**

```
<?php 

require_once('../../../../../Mage.php');

class WACI_CustomerExt_Model_Observer 
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function customer_register_success( Varien_Event_Observer $observer )
    {

        $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->loadDefault('notify_new_customer');
        $emailTemplate
            ->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name'))
            ->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email'))
            ->setTemplateSubject('New customer registered');
        $result = $emailTemplate->send(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'),(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'), $observer->getCustomer()->getData());

    }

}
```

**local/en_us/template/notify_new_customer.html**

```
New customer registration:<br />
Name: {{var name}}<br />
Email: {{var email}}<br />
... you win a pickle.
```

Two things that seem suspect: 
I doubt i have my observer set up correctly in my config. 
I expect that I need to include app/mage.php (but it does no do this in the example).

I'm not getting any errors, per se, in the logs, so I'm assuming the event isn't getting either registered or properly handled.

Whatever the case, in typical Magento form, my attempt at this isn't working.

I'd appreciate some advice ;D

Cheers

Comment: You don't need to include the app/mage.php as this has already been done in the /index.php. I would add logging into the `customer_register_success` function to determine if it's working or not...if it's not then you haven't configured it correctly. If it is, then something else is going on

Comment: Ah - yeah. no need to include mage. Too much ajax lately. - I had been checking logs but took it out at some point. Added back in and it definitely points at an include error. Thx.

Comment: @CCBlackburn = ok, i'm getting an email through now, but the template isn't getting either read or processed. Whatever the case, the body of the email is empty. Any idea?

Comment: ... had the template file in my theme/variation/locale and not app/locale... grr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging definitely produced an include error

```
Failed opening 'Mage/Waci/Customerext/Model/Observer.php'
```

obviously, my class reference needed the correct case.

```
<events>
            <!-- regisration success -->
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                    <WACI_CustomerExt>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>WACI_CustomerExt/Observer</class>
                        <method>customer_register_success</method>
                    </WACI_CustomerExt>
                </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
        </events>
```

Also, slight syntax error came up in the send() call right about here : `/email'),(Mage::getSt`.

Anyway, as per usual, config was my problem.