# Send Confirmation email to the admin email

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.7

I'm a newbie in magento and I searched all over the google to find a way on how to execute the idea of mine but I couldn't found a result. What he want to happen is to send him a email when new account was created. Is there any options in magento that support this one? Please help....

Thanks,
Sherwin

Comment: did u try any of the solution mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11312535/534525

Comment: yes, That's one works thank you sir. Do you know sir how to send this one in multiple mail? I mean the approval is has a Carbon Copy to other mails? Thank you very much sir..