# Magento core module Events

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Is there adminhtml_permissions_user_save_before Event in magento Core events ?

I have create an Observer to observe an ADMIN USER before_save Event Because i want to perform a specific operation depending on role type and i dont want to edit the core module.

EDIT:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Eco_Perm>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </Eco_Perm>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <perm>
            <class>Eco_Perm_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>perms</resourceModel>
        </perm>
        <perms>
            <class>Eco_Perm_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <perm>
                    <table>perm/observer</table>
                </perm>
            </entities>
        </perms>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <perm>
            <setup>
                <module>Eco_Perm</module>
                <class>Eco_Perm_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </perm>
    </resources>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <Eco_Perm_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>perm/observer</class>
                    <method>testProductedit</method>
                </Eco_Perm_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>

        <adminhtml_permissions_user_save_before>
            <observer>
                <Eco_Perm_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>perm/observer</class>
                    <method>updatepermer</method>
                </Eco_Perm_Model_Observer>
            </observer>
        </adminhtml_permissions_user_save_before>

    </events>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <perm>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Eco_Perm</module>
                <frontName>perm</frontName>
            </args>
        </perm>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <perm>
                <file>perm.xml</file>
            </perm>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <menu>
        <perm translate="title" module="adminhtml">
            <title>Affiliate</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <set_time>
                    <title>Shipper's</title>
                    <action>perm/adminhtml_index</action>
                </set_time>
            </children>
        </perm>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the event you are looking for is `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_permissions_user_save`

Checkout out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2968705/1957705).It will help you in tracing the event you want.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and the reference post of Alan Storm. i also tried "admin_user_save_before" Event but am getting the following warning message: :                                                                                                                               Warning: Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent() [mage-core-model-app.dispatchevent]: Node no longer exists

Comment: I think the typo might be the culprit.Change <observer> to <observers>