# Events for admin user create in Magento

Tags: magento, admin

I am working on a new project. I am facing a problem where I need to save the details when an admin user is created. I am planning to use an observer to catch the event. I need to know that is there any event in Magento defined for getting the admin user creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in your config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <admin_user_save_before>
            <observers>
                <magepal>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>magepal/observer</class>
                    <method>handleAdminUserSaveBefore</method>
                </magepal>
            </observers>
        </admin_user_save_before>
```

Then check to see if `$user->getId()` exist

Also take a look @ [Magento core module Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107972/magento-core-module-events)

Comment: How to check if selected admin user  logged in and using a condition like if selected admin user logged in, the dashboard select with selected store view